# Printing reduceByKey output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to print the output after reduceByKey

I tried  things like
totalsByAge.foreach{ i =>println("Value = " + i )}

I have a couple of lines of code 
val totalsByAgeEntry = rdd.mapValues(x => (x, 1))

val totalsByAge = totalsByAgeEntry.reduceByKey( (x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))

I want to print the tuple that gets when reduceByKey is called. I dont print the output after (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2) is computed.

I know that the data created after reduceByKey is something like:
(x,((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
But how can I print that

Comment: `foreach` is executed on the **Executors**, you are on the **Driver**, you wont see the output. Either use `collect` to retrieve a _local_ `Array` of tuples and call `foreach` on that. Or, use `reduceByKeyLocally` which will give you a _local_ `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `reduceByKey` is performed by the executors, and `println` prints the output in the executor's standard output. The executor's stdout is usually available at `master.application.ip.address:8080`.

If you want to print/view your data you can do that in several ways. For instance: 1) by applying `totalByAge.take(numberOfLines).foreach(println)`; 2) by collecting (`.collect()`) the RDD to the driver; and 3) by converting the RDD to a Dataframe and then applying `.show()`.

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)] = 
    sparkContext
        .parallelize(Vector(1, 2, 3))
        .map(i => (i, 1))
        .reduceByKey(_ + _)
rdd.take(10).foreach(println) // take the first 10 lines and print them
rdd.collect().foreach(println) // centralize the entire RDD and print it
import spark.implicits._
rdd.toDF().show(10) // conver to dataframe and show the first 10 lines
```